# Validating certificate using NodeJs Crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I'm running a sever in NodeJs whose certificate will be stored in DB as a string (for security purposes). I would like to validate it and it's expiration date, how can I do that?

I looked into 'Crypto' but I could not find a method that can do that.

For example:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDNTCCAh2gAwIBAgIUJqrw/9EDZbp4DExaLjh0vSAHyBgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwFjEUMBIGA1UEAxMLbXl2YXVsdC5jb20wHhcNMTcxMjA4MTkyMzIwWhcNMjcx
MjA2MTkyMzQ5WjAWMRQwEgYDVQQDEwtteXZhdWx0LmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKY/vJ6sRFym+yFYUneoVtDmOCaDKAQiGzQw0IXL
BT55jevSPVVu
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using package x509.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/x509

```
const x509 = require('x509');
var cert = x509.parseCert(__dirname + '/certs/nodejitsu.com.crt');
/*
cert = { subject:
   { countryName: 'US',
     postalCode: '10010',
     stateOrProvinceName: 'NY',
     localityName: 'New York',
     streetAddress: '902 Broadway, 4th Floor',
     organizationName: 'Nodejitsu',
     organizationalUnitName: 'PremiumSSL Wildcard',
     commonName: '*.nodejitsu.com' },
  issuer:
   { countryName: 'GB',
     stateOrProvinceName: 'Greater Manchester',
     localityName: 'Salford',
     organizationName: 'COMODO CA Limited',
     commonName: 'COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA' },
  notBefore: Sun Oct 28 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  notAfter: Wed Nov 26 2014 18:59:59 GMT-0500 (EST),
  altNames: [ '*.nodejitsu.com', 'nodejitsu.com' ],
  signatureAlgorithm: 'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  fingerPrint: 'E4:7E:24:8E:86:D2:BE:55:C0:4D:41:A1:C2:0E:06:96:56:B9:8E:EC',
  publicKey: {
    algorithm: 'rsaEncryption',
    e: '65537',
    n: '.......' } }
*/
```